# Excel VBA Outlook - Subject Contains Is Not Finding Reply Emails

Tags: excel, vba, outlook, restrict

How do I get the following Excel VBA code to return all emails with subjects containing 'Timesheet 06/19/20'?

The below code does return "Timesheet 06/19/20 - Name (EmpId) ". However, **IT DOES NOT RETURN** "[EXTERNAL] RE: Timesheet 06/19/20 - Name (EmpId) ". What am I doing wrong?

```
     Public Function Test()
         Dim Folder As Outlook.Folder, MailItems As Outlook.Items, MailItem As Outlook.MailItem
         Dim Filter As String
    
         Filter = "@SQL=urn:schemas:httpmail:subject" & "" & " ci_phrasematch 'Timesheet 06/19/20'"
         Set Folder = Outlook.Application.GetNamespace("MAPI").GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)
         Set MailItems = Folder.Items.Restrict(Filter)
         For Each MailItem In MailItems
             Debug.Print MailItem.Subject
         Next MailItem
     End Function
```

Note, if I change the filter to search on "[EXTERNAL] RE: Timesheet 06/19/20" it finds the email. Obviously this won't work for my solution as I need to search for "Timesheet 06/19/20" to accommodate the original, forward, and reply emails.

Thank you for any help you can give!

Comment: That works fine for me: performs a partial match on the supplied string and returns both mails.

Comment: Thank you for verifying Ted! That helped me to dig deeper and saw where an "on error resume next" statement which was hiding an error caused by the subject "Undeliverable: Timesheet 06/19/20 - Name (EmpId) <Action Required>". Not sure why that is throwing an error in the for each statement. I'll post what I find.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure why but an email with the subject "Undeliverable: Timesheet 06/19/20 - Name (EmpId) " was throwing an error which caused the code to exit the for loop early. The below code fixed the error from being thrown.

Maybe someone has an explanation as to why the above subject likes an index count for loop better?

```
Public Function Test()
    Dim Folder As Outlook.Folder, MailItems As Outlook.Items, MailItem As Outlook.MailItem
    Dim Filter As String, idx As Long
    
    Filter = "@SQL=urn:schemas:httpmail:subject" & "" & " ci_phrasematch 'Timesheet 06/19/20'"
    
    Set Folder = Outlook.Application.GetNamespace("MAPI").GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)
    Set MailItems = Folder.Items.Restrict(Filter)
    For idx = 1 To MailItems.Count
        Debug.Print MailItems(idx).Subject
    Next idx
    
End Function
```

Comment: I have posted the explanation. You must check the underlying item class in the loop for each item. An Outlook folder may contain different item types.

Comment: It makes sense to mark the post as answer finally.

Answer (score 1):

You need to remember that the `Items` collection may contain different types of items, not only mail items. So, it is better to define an item as an object and check the item's type at runtime before accessing any property or method specific to a particular item type. For example:

```
Public Function Test()
         Dim Folder As Outlook.Folder, MailItems As Outlook.Items, item As Object
         Dim Filter As String
    
         Filter = "@SQL=urn:schemas:httpmail:subject" & "" & " ci_phrasematch 'Timesheet 06/19/20'"
         Set Folder = Outlook.Application.GetNamespace("MAPI").GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)
         Set MailItems = Folder.Items.Restrict(Filter)
         For Each item In MailItems
             Debug.Print TypeName(item)
         Next item
     End Function
```

Read more about the `Restrict` method in the [How To: Use Restrict method to retrieve Outlook mail items from a folder](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/09/23/outlook-restrict-method-retrieve-mail/) article.